# XamlWriter.Save() is not serializing DependencyProperties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamlwriter, uielementcollection

Consider the following XAML from my UserControl:

```
<TextBlock Text="HelloWorld" Loaded="TextBlock_OnLoaded" />
```

And the associated event handler:

```
private void TextBlock_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var xaml = XamlWriter.Save(sender);
    Console.WriteLine(xaml);
}
```

When the TextBlock is loaded, the following output is written to the Console:

```
<TextBlock Text="HelloWorld" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" />
```

Now consider this alternative XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="HelloWorld" Loaded="TextBlock_OnLoaded" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Now when the TextBlock is loaded, the following output is written to the Console:

```
<TextBlock xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" />
<TextBlock xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" />
<TextBlock xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" />
......
```

Notice that the TextProperty is no longer being serialized.

If the following TextProperty assignment is added before the call to XamlWriter.Save():

```
private void TextBlock_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
    if (textBlock != null)
    {
        textBlock.Text = textBlock.Text;
    }

    var xaml = XamlWriter.Save(sender);
    Console.WriteLine(xaml);
}
```

Then when the TextBlock is loaded, the following output is written to the Console:

```
<TextBlock Text="HelloWorld" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" />
<TextBlock Text="HelloWorld" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" />
<TextBlock Text="HelloWorld" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" />
......
```

Notice that the TextProperty is again being serialized.

This [blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20150810005407/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/16/xamlwriter.aspx) explains that "... if the property is backed by a DependencyProperty ... the property is only written if it is actually set."

It appears that the TextProperty is indeed being set in the first usage example, but not in the second usage example with the ListBox and DataTemplate.

Can anyone explain why this is the case, and how to overcome this obstacle?

My best guess is that the XAML parser is somehow setting the TextBlock state internally instead of calling SetValue on the dependency property, but I'm not sure why it would do this only for elements inside a DataTemplate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XamlWriter.Save` appears to only serialize ***locally***-set values. In XAML, values can come from [multiple levels of sources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#listing).

When you set `TextBlock.Text` directly, you are looking at a "local value" set (precedence 3). However, when you set it inside a data template, you are setting template properties (precedence 4). By writing

```
textBlock.Text = textBlock.Text;
```

you are actually transforming that into a local property set (precedence 3)!

If you look at the [some of the source code involved in XamlWriter.Save](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Markup/Primitives/ElementMarkupObject.cs,284100a9dd5854be), you can see ([line 819](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Markup/Primitives/ElementMarkupObject.cs,819)) that it explicitly reads the local value of the property.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure what a good work-around is for this. XamlWriter has [known limitations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms754193.aspx). You an try inheriting from [`XamlDesignerSerializationManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.markup.xamldesignerserializationmanager.aspx) and calling the [`XamlWriter.Save(Object, XamlDesignerSerializationManager)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms590434.aspx) overload, but it doesn't look very promising. More likely, you will have to either do what you do above, or write your own serialization routine (at least Microsoft has made their source readily available as a guide).

Comment: The .Net framework source links are dead. Here is a link for version 4.8 of . Net framework : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Markup/XamlWriter.cs,5a926799f0b416e9

Answer (score 1):

In light of [NextInLine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113374/nextinline)'s answer, I've come up with the following work around:

```
public static IEnumerable<DependencyProperty> GetDependencyProperties(this DependencyObject obj)
{
    var propertyDescriptors = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj, new Attribute[]
    {
        new PropertyFilterAttribute(PropertyFilterOptions.All)
    });

    return (from PropertyDescriptor pd in propertyDescriptors
            let dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(pd)
            where dpd != null
            select dpd.DependencyProperty).ToList();
}

public static IEnumerable<DependencyProperty> GetUpdatedDependencyProperties(this DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (from property in obj.GetDependencyProperties().Where(x => !x.ReadOnly)
            let metaData = property.GetMetadata(obj.GetType())
            let defaultValue = metaData.DefaultValue
            let currentValue = obj.GetValue(property)
            where currentValue != defaultValue
            select property).ToList();
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
foreach (var updatedProperty in dependencyObject.GetUpdatedDependencyProperties())
{
    dependencyObject.SetValue(updatedProperty, dependencyObject.GetValue(updatedProperty));
}
```

This will force `XamlWriter.Save(dependencyObject)` to serialize all of the `dependencyObject` properties that were updated in XAML.

Comment: I'm glad you added this - hopefully it will help someone else in the same boat.

Comment: where exactly does the method GetDependencyProperties come from?